# JS - Remove optional/potential quotation marks at the beginning and end of all strings in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, replace

Tinkering for hours with the following challenge:

There is an array of strings. Some of these strings might have at the beginning and end quotation marks. These quotation marks, if they exist, should be removed.

An example:

```
var quotes = [""Hello World"", "Hey Earth", ""\Hot here\""]
```

desired outcome:

```
var quotes = ["Hello World", "Hey Earth", "Hot here"]
```

For a single quote I tried for removing the quotation marks something like this...

```
var newquote = quote.replace(/^\"|\"$/g, '');
```

but I struggle with doing this with the full array...
so that I can later use the array in

```
const regex = new RegExp(`(${this.quotes.join('|')})`, 'g');
```

Anyone an idea how this is doable?
Sorry, still JS/React newbie. Thanks so much for helping out.

---

UPDATE:

Regarding the quotes example. I know ""Hello World"" is not correct syntax, though unfortunately for a console.log(quotes) I get for example these data ... see [0] and [3] ... [image]

Comment: `var quotes = [""Hello World"", "Hey Earth", ""\Hot here\""]` isn't valid syntax

Comment: You need to map the array and apply the conversion to every item

Comment: `["\"Hello World\"", "\"Hey Earth\"", "Hot here"].map(x => x.replace(/\"/g, ""))` Assuming you actually have those values in the array ... which are valid vs the ones you had which are not valid JS

Comment: thanks @FrankerZ, please see my update above... I have strange data...

Comment: Can you actually post sample data. It seems there is more to the story there ...

Comment: Observation: `"`, `“`, and `”` are three different characters.

Comment: @Akrion do you need more than above in the update? The data comes from text parts that were highlighted by a user.

Comment: No we are fine now ... you have `“` vs `"`

Comment: @YvonC In the future, you should be able to copy/paste right from your console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have `“` vs `"` so you could simply do:

```js
var data = ["“Hello World“", "“Hey Earth“", "\"Hot here\""]

console.log(data.map(x => x.replace(/^[“”"]+|[“”"]+$/g, "")))
```

result: `["Hello World", "Hey Earth", "Hot here"]`

Note: Updated as per valid comment and **catch** by @revo. Thanks!

`^[“”"]+|[“”"]+$` - The regex here matches anything that `starts` and `ends` with `“` or extra `"`. Since we use `replace` and `/g` (global) it would replace it in the entire string.

Comment: or more precisely `x.replace(/^[“”"]+|[“”"]+$/g, "")`

Comment: Agreed. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Since the array quotes don't have a valid syntax I adapt your input array to:

`var quotes = ["\"Hello World\"", "Hey Earth", "\"Hot here\""]`

To process all the elements of the array you can use an map:

`quotes.map(quote => quote.replace(/^\"|\"$/g, ''));`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code Should be like this: `var quotes = ["\"Hello World\"", "Hey Earth", "\"Hot here\""];` 
And if your quotes like this then try this: `

```js
var quotes = ["\"Hello World\"", "Hey Earth", "\"Hot here\""];
var newquotes = quotes.map(n => n.replace(/["']/g, ''));
console.log(newquotes);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can try switching from an array to string & process the output:

```js
var quotes = ["\"Hello World\"", "Hey Earth", "\"\Hot here\""];
var output = quotes.join().replace(/"/g, "").split(",");
console.log(output);
```